# How to only use absolute urls for links and images

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-7, view

How can I make Drupal generate absolute urls for links and img paths from my module?
Or at least through Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your module (replace "hook" with your module name):

```
hook_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  $options['absolute'] = TRUE;
}
```